# Visual Effect "Light" of Greasepencil doesn't exist

Tags: grease-pencil

I have seen lighting effects being used in a 2019 Greasepencil tutorial, but it is not listed in the Visual Effects tab. Is it removed from Blender?

Comment: Could you add a link to the tutorial you saw?

Comment: Maccesch, I think this is the tutorial Mugalugaga is referring to: https://cloud.blender.org/training/grease-pencil-fundamentals/ I had the same problem following this tutorial but Wilks answer set me straight. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Greasepencil's draw-engine was refactored and now GP objects can interact with 3d lights, so the light effect was removed. See point 1.3 in this [post](https://code.blender.org/2020/02/grease-pencil-refactor/).